# intel sdk vd phonegap for packaging web app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, intel, phonegap-build

I'm in Africa and have some Intel people coming to preach to us tomorrow at a Hackerspace here.

I like writing Javascript, html5, css3 for my apps. Is there a difference between using [Intel SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools) and Phonegap/Phonegap Build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Phonegap, you need to build from a native-development SDK, and customize things for each platform you target.

With the XDK, everything you need to write from scratch or put a preexisting web app on mobile is included in the single ~125M installer; code in the embedded editor or another of your choice, emulate on a bunch of devices, test on your own phone/tablet by scanning a QR code, and build out to any of a dozen platforms (including iOS, Android, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8) without any code changes.  The App Designer (drag-and-drop interface) is also  included with the download, but optional to use.

If you need low-level interaction beyond what is available in the XDK API (http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/amdocs/lib/Article-JSAPICheatSheet3.4.0.pdf?r=8995) you can write a custom plugin.

A post about the comparison between the two is available at http://developer.html5dev-software.intel.com/?q=node/153 (this uses the old XDK; the new one has more and better features)